# Как проверить тип валидаторов в FormGroup?

Tags: angular2, form, angular, forms

Angular: 7
Есть компонент в который передаю инстанс `FormGroup` и название поля.
Если поле не валидное то отображается ошибка.
Нужно сделать так, чтобы для каждой валидации показывались разные ошибки:
для *Validation.required*: "Required field" 
для *Validation.email*: "Email is not valid" 
и так далее
Сейчас компонент выглядит так:
HTML

```
<div *ngIf="form.controls[fieldName].touched && form.controls[fieldName].invalid"
     class="alert alert-danger mb-1" role="alert">
    <div>
        Invalid field
    </div>
</div>
```

TS

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup } from "@angular/forms";

@Component({
    selector: 'cts-field-error',
    templateUrl: './field-error.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./field-error.component.sass']
})
export class FieldErrorComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input() form: FormGroup;
    @Input() fieldName: string;

    constructor() {}

    ngOnInit() {}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`form.controls[fieldName]` - так нельзя делать, так как это похоже на велосипед.

Вы в любом случае знаете все контролы внутри формы, потому что вы сами создаете ее.

Как делаю я? Для удобства, чтобы не плясать с самой формой - я создаю геттеры для контролов:

```
public form = new FormGroup({
  email: new FormControl(null, [Validators.email])
});

public get email(): AbstractControl {
  return this.form.get('email')!;
}
```

Во входной параметр самого компонента `app-cts-field-error` мы уже можем не передавать всю форму и название поля, а только сам контрол:

```
<app-cts-field-error *ngIf="email.errors" [control]="email"></app-cts-field-error>
```

`FormControl.prototype.errors` может иметь только 2 значения - `null` и объект. Если `null` - значит контрол валидный и ошибок нету.

Внутри компонента `app-cts-field-error` можно проверять если ли ошибка у контрола через метод `hasError`:

```
<div *ngIf="control.hasError('required')">This field is required</div>
<div *ngIf="control.hasError('email')">Email is invalid</div>
```

P.S. строки внутри метода `hasError` имеют прямое отношение к статическим свойствам класса `Validators`. То есть если у вас есть валидация с регуляркой:

```
Validators.pattern('^[a-zA-Z]+$')
```

То ошибку можно проверять через `control.hasError('pattern')`.

Comment: Геттеры выглядят хорошо, спасибо за подсказку!